# How can I open a rect-bootstrap modal dialog from another Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, react-bootstrap

I learn react and have this [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/) Modal dialog.

I wonder how can I use it in another Component.
Here is the example from that page and it's straight forward the Component take care of it's self open/close dialog:

```
function Example() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
        Launch demo modal
      </Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

But what if the `Button` that open the dialog is in another `Component` and I want to send in a `props` like show/hide like this:
(or is this a bad approche?)

```
function Example(props) {
  const{ show } = props;

  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
  const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Woohoo, you're reading this text in a modal!</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

render(<Example />);
```

As you see this will not work the `show`is already defined...
I have tried a number of way to understand the logic like this for example:

```
function Example(props) {
    let { show } = props;
    const [showing, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => {
        show = false;
        setShow(false);
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={show || showing} onHide={handleClose} centered>
```

I open but it does not render on `setShow(false)` I think it's the same prop's something

The reason for this is that the dialog must be opened from two different locations so I must do like this.

Please advice here is full code in where I want to open the dialog:
(this Component can be opened individually from two locations)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Offline } from 'react-detect-offline';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ProfilePageAuthenticated from './ProfilePageAuthenticated';
import ProfilePageAnonymous from './ProfilePageAnonymous';
import LinkAccounts from './LinkAccounts';
import SummaryPage from './SummaryPage';
import ContributePage from './ContributePage';

const Dashboard = props => {
    const { show } = props;
    const [showing, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose} centered>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>User Profile</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <ProfilePageAuthenticated />
                    <ProfilePageAnonymous />
                    <LinkAccounts />
                    <SummaryPage />
                    <ContributePage />
                    <Offline>
                        <div
                            style={{
                                marginTop: 40,
                                display: 'flex',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                color: 'red',
                            }}
                        >
                            It appears you don't have an active Internet connection!
                        </div>
                    </Offline>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={handleClose}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};

const Button = styled.button`
    height: 68px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: var(--button-text-color);
    padding: 0 1rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: var(--button-background);
    border-radius: 6px;
    &:hover {
        background: var(--button-hover-background);
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        display: none;
    }
`;
export default Dashboard;
```

Here one location that open the dialog: and it hase the `Button` who open

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';

function SignedInButton() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    return (
        <div>
            <Button className="button is-large" onClick={handleShow}>
                <span className="icon is-medium">
                    <i className="fas fa-user" />
                </span>
            </Button>
            <Dashboard show={show} />
        </div>
    );
}

const Button = styled.button`
    height: 68px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: var(--button-text-color);
    padding: 0 1rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: var(--button-background);
    border-radius: 6px;
    &:hover {
        background: var(--button-hover-background);
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        display: none;
    }
`;
export default SignedInButton;
```

Comment: in which component do you want to open/close the modal from Example Component ?

Comment: I updated with code

Comment: is SignedInButton a child or parent component of the Example component ? because if not you'll need to have to create a global store of your application, with libraries like Redux...

Comment: yes the `SignedInButton` is the parent that open the `Dashboard` that have my dialog. Also I open the `Dashboard` from another Component like doing `import Dashboard from './Dashboard';` in both Components. Is this bad? I also use React Redux and could `mapStateToProps` open the dialog!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to share the state of `show` between the `Dashboard` and `SignInButton`, as only one modal can be open at the time in the application.

You should handle the `show` state, `handleShow` function and `handleClose` function in the top component, which, in this case, is `SignedInButton`. Then, you should pass `show` boolean and `handleClose` function as props down to the child component, in this case `Dashboard`.

### SignedInButton

```
function SignedInButton() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

    return (
        <div>
            <Button className="button is-large" onClick={handleShow}>
                <span className="icon is-medium">
                    <i className="fas fa-user" />
                </span>
            </Button>
            <Dashboard show={show} onClose={handleClose}/>
        </div>
    );
}
// ...
```

### Dashboard

```
const Dashboard = props => {
    const { show, onClose } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Modal show={show} onHide={onClose} centered>
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title>User Profile</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <ProfilePageAuthenticated />
                    <ProfilePageAnonymous />
                    <LinkAccounts />
                    <SummaryPage />
                    <ContributePage />
                    <Offline>
                        <div
                            style={{
                                marginTop: 40,
                                display: 'flex',
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                justifyContent: 'center',
                                color: 'red',
                            }}
                        >
                            It appears you don't have an active Internet connection!
                        </div>
                    </Offline>
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={onClose}>
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thanks but I think I must rethink because I get two `Dashboard` Components and I think I could make it work so there is only one right?  I do this `<Dashboard show={show} onClose={handleClose}/>` from two Components! I use the [React-Sight](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-sight/aalppolilappfakpmdfdkpppdnhpgifn) and see there are two

Comment: think Redux is better??

Comment: Yes it creates [two components](https://snipboard.io/CtYSky.jpg) the  React-Sight is grate to learn

Comment: @Kid It is possible to use redux / react-redux as well. In that case you have to store the `show` boolean in the redux store, and change the function to dispatch an ACTION.

Comment: Although, for this use case, I would recommend against it. Imo, Redux should be used as little as possible, as it adds a lot of complexity for little gain. Usually, it should be reserved for authentication variables and other global variables. The rule of thumb is that if you aren't sure if you need it, you don't: https://redux.js.org/faq/general#when-should-i-use-redux. However, if the goal is practice, then by all mean, go for it

Comment: Thanks the Modal `Dashboard` can be opened from many places and connect to Google Firestore for user to see stats and change username and stuff. I use Redux Saga and Actions for Firestore and I read up on [this tutorial](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/creating-a-modal-component-the-redux-way-cf9f4c5497dd) about it. Redux abstracts away this dialog in a good way like, Single responsibility principle SRP, btw my app is a Redux [app](https://github.com/erikswed/Greta-100-React-Web-App) already, there you see the modal dialog in the "user" Button, but I also want's to access it from elsewhere